# Answer shows different even though the output is coming correctly

Tags: dart, data-structures

I was practicing some leetcode and I am pretty new to it. So, there is this problem where you need to shift the 0s to the right. I wrote the code and the output is coming as expected but the results yields `[]`.
Can anyone explain what's wrong?
Here is the snippet of my code.[image]

And here is the result.

[image]

As you can clearly see in the `stdout`, the output is correct but the answer is coming as an empty list. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: `nums = nonZeroArray` just reassigns the `nums` parameter, which is local to your function.  It does not *mutate* the `List` that `nums` originally referred to, which is what the caller presumably expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The question is based on Inplace operations and your logic is quite correct. I will explain with 3 things so it will be clear to you.

**1. Good programming practice:-**

The output yields [], because there is clear statement in 19th line

```
//19 nums.clear();
//20 nums=nonZeroArray;
```

**Idea:-** nums is cleared. contents of nonZeroArray is copied to nums.

**Actual thing:-** But in this case if we use clear, then result will be cleared i.e [] and 20th line is not having any impact.

**Proof:-**
->As the question is in place traversal, don't use clear statement. This is bad programming practice.
Instead of 19th and 20th line you can try this

```
for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
{
   nums[i]=nonZeroArray[I];
}
```

Don't use clear, instead of that copy element by element you will get result.

**2. Logic correction:-**
Even after doing this, you will get error because there is logic error in code.

The question says if array is [0,1,0,3,12]. The output should be [1,3,12,0,0]. pushing zeros to end.

In line 2, no need of sort function. suppose take example of arr=[0,2,1]. the output should be [2,1,0]. if we sort in line 2, then output will be [1,2,0] which is wrong. so don't sort.

**The final corrected code will be:-**

```
class Solution {
 void moveZeroes(List<int> nums) {
    List<int> nonZeroArray=[];
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
      if(nums[i]!=0){
          nonZeroArray.add(nums[i]);
      }
    }

    if(nums.length != nonZeroArray.length){
       int rem=nums.length-nonZeroArray.length;
       for(int i=0; i<rem; i++){
           nonZeroArray.add(0);
       }
       // print(nonZeroArray);
     }
    // nums.clear();
    // nums=nonZeroArray;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
       nums[i]=nonZeroArray[I];
    }
   }
  }
```

**3. Good programming practice with Inplace traversal** -> don't try to use additional variables (like nonZeroArray her). Try to solve in nums itself in case of in place traversal,

**Alternative code:-**

```
class Solution {
   void moveZeroes(List<int> nums) {
   int listLenght = nums.length;
   nums.removeWhere((element) => element == 0);

   int listRemaningLenght = listLenght - nums.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < listRemaningLenght; i++) {
     nums.add(0);
   }
 }
}
```

I hope this cleared your doubt.

Thank you.
Happy Coding.

Regards:-

**Rakshath U Shetty**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).